# Sequel relations and SQL functions

Tags: ruby, sequel, sequel-gem

I am using Ruby [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) and I need to find the total amount spent by a customer since a specific date. This code is working:

```
customer = Customer.where(username: params[:username]).first
unless customer
  exit
end
Purchases.where(customer: customer).and('date < ?', params[:date]).sum(:amount)
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to use the Model relation between Customer and Purchases and not use a where clause to find the Purchases, so that the code can look cleaner.

I was thinking about something like `customer.Purchases.where(...).sum(...)` but it doesn't work.

Any idea if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned

> was thinking about something like customer.Purchases.where(...).sum(...) but it doesn't work.

and in your comment in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912553/676874) you mention the relation with `customer.purchases` already exists.

Then you should also have a `purchases_dataset`-method. It is a `Sequel::SQLite::Dataset` and returns models.

So you could try:

```
customer.purchases_dataset.where('date < ?', params[:date]).sum(:amount)
```

(If it does not work: Can you please post your table and model definition to make a test)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, didn't know about the _dataset thing. Perfect!

Comment: I detected it last week ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't able to use associations declared in model in order to join a table.

[Sequel documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/querying_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Qualification) proposes only following way to generate right SQL:

```
Album.join(:artists, :id=>:artist_id)
# SELECT * FROM albums
# INNER JOIN artists ON artists.id = albums.artist_id
```

In you case it can look like this:

```
Customer.join(:purchases, customer_id: :id).where('date < ?', params[:date]).sum(:amount)
```